# how to set LatLng as a numeric value

Tags: angularjs, json, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am having trouble trying to display markers on a map from a JSON file. The map loads fine, yet it doesn't display any markers on it...when I look into the javascript console I can see I am getting a continuous error (although the lat and lon objects all display the correct positions with console.log). I will post the error below along with my marker functionality. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**the error:**

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bzZ6.jpg)

**marker functions:**

```
displayGoogleMap(){
let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(43.653908,-79.384293);
let mapOptions = {
center:latLng,
zoom:12,
mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement,   mapOptions);
}


getMarkers(){
//this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json').map((res)=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
this.http.get('http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR?limit=500').map((res)=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>{
this.addMarkersMap(data);
});

}


addMarkersMap(markers){
for(let marker of markers)
{
var loc = {lat:  marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lat , lon: marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lng};

  console.log(loc);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: loc,
  map: this.map
  });

}
}
```

**json feed:**

http://app.toronto.ca/cc_sr_v1_app/data/edc_eventcal_APR?limit=500

Comment: Rename key name **lon to lng** `var loc = {lat:  marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lat , lng: marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lng};`

Answer (score 0):

The position should be defined with lng not lon:

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
```

not

```
var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lon: 131.044};
```

so just change your code to:

```
var loc = {lat:  marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lat , lng: marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'].lng};
```

or just

```
var loc = marker.calEvent.locations[0]['coords'];
```